# Parent View to show SnackBar for a Layout with Data Binding

Tags: android

This is my activity layout that uses Data Binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="myData"
            type="MyData" />
    </data>
    <ScrollView>
       <LinearLayout>
         -- More contents
       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
 </layout>
```

I want to show a SnackBar on this Activity. But I have tried using the ID of LinearLayout, ScrollView & the root layout. But the SnackBar never shows up. Has anyone attempted to show SnackBar on activities that uses data binding?

Comment: Just make sure your root layout (the ScrollView in your current code) is a CoordinatorLayout and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

Let`s say you want to show Snackbar on MainActivity. Here key is `activityMainBinding.getRoot()`

```
   Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(activityMainBinding.getRoot(), "Your_Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
   snackbar.show();
```